# How server-logic-heavy should a view be?

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller, debugging, codeigniter

I'm debugging a codeigniter app that intermittently crashes (500 error) when showing a list of blog posts.

The crash happens 20-30% of page reloads - and seems to be related to either a memory issue of server misconfiguration.

***First*** I went down the controller by doing `print_r($array); exit;` just below each array that is sent to the view page. No problems if you simply output the array (without passing through view) -- there is never a timeout.

So I don't think the query logic is faulty. Also CI's profiler shows query times <.001 when the page loads correctly (when it crashes I get 500 error and cannot read the profiler's info).

***Next*** I moved on to `print_r` the view's HTML which has loops for the arrays sent by controller. And that is where there's a bottleneck that occasionally will cause the 500 error.

The app is designed in such a way that a single view handles all of the arrays sent by the controller and builds an HTML page with the final output.

Because of this, the view has a lot of PHP logic. Several array splits to insert ad units before running foreach loops, conditionals testing for post parameters, nested foreach loops and such.

It is pretty complex but perfectly readable. However I wonder if it's too much logic, and if the load of this logic should be separated into smaller fragments (multiple views) and then merged together into a final HTML string.

The view has

- 30-50 `if / elseif`, some nested
- 6-7 `foreach`, some nested
- 5 `array_splice` numerous `empty` and `isset`

What's your take on this issue? Do you typically avoid logic heavy views? Any advice?

***Please note I'm not asking about "cleaning" views for the sake of webdesigners etc as in other SO discussions. My point here is if this structure could be causing my timeouts and what would be the potential solution.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's not a question of how readable the template code is - there's a strong correlation between complexity and the presence of bugs. [Cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) is one way to measure complexity; from what you've posted, this template has a cyclomatic complexity of at least 60. In all our projects, I aim for a cyclomatic complexity of < 8, and get panicky when we get to 12.

I wouldn't be surprised if your view code contains a bug - not just a time-out thing, but some bizarre route through the logic tree that you can't quite picture by looking at the code.

The Williams template library gives you several tools to do this - for instance, you can define alternate views to deal with the "if question, render like this, if post render like that" logic. You can also use regions to your benefit here.

There's an assumption that because views deal with the user interface, they are less important - but that's simply not true.

So, let's assume you refactor your view into a simpler structure. Will this affect processor load? Well - uh - depends.

Usually, "maintainability" and "performance" have to be traded off against eachother. The classic example is assembler code versus interpreted languages - for most people, assembler is hard to maintain, whereas interpreted scripting languages are far more tractable; on the other hand, there's no doubt which is faster.

In your case, I think the total amount of code will increase - "extract method" as a refactoring, for instance, would increase the amount of code by a few lines - but it should be easier to cache. It should also be easier to identify exactly where the bug occurs.

Comment: great advice @neville, quite impressive how nesting of loops and conditionals gets out of control in the view and bogs down the output - does breaking down complexity in chunks relieve processor load potentially alleviating this - at the end the same number of conditionals & loops will be required, but I guess that if they occur in discrete modules they are less taxing?

Comment: @torr - updated answer in response to your comment. To be honest, I don't believe the 500 is occuring because you're taxing the processor too much - I've never seen that happen, even in more complex pages. It's far more likely to be some bizarre trip through the conditionals that's triggering the error...

Answer (score 1):

> What's your take on this issue?

THere is a bottleneck where you pinpointed it.  Right now the view performance is unacceptable if it is 500 (timing out).  It needs to be fixed if it is to become usable.

> Do you typically avoid logic heavy views

Always.  This is what MVC pattern is designed to do.  Keep as much logic to your controllers as possible,  Views should be presentation only.

It seems too much is trying to be put into one view.  If you want to post some code it would be easier to make suggestions as to what needs to be looked at.  To me the biggest offender is `conditionals testing for post parameters`.  I would think that this almost certainly belongs in your controller.  What are these post params being used for??

If the post params dictate the output type, it would be cleaner to seperate into different views, instead of handling multiple different output types in your one super view.

Comment: thanks @dm - the view code is 400 lines long and impractical to post - but thee's a lot of logic in it that will generate HTML based on the content of the arrays

Comment: @torr, there is all sorts of things you can do to speed up.  If there are static parts of the view, you can break them up into their own templates and cache them.  You can optimize/refactor the logic that is being done in the view currently.

Comment: super view it is - post params are for ex: `if a post is a blog entry, display data using this HTML block, elseif a post is a question, use that HTML structure, etc`

Comment: @torr, i believe each one of those types should have their own templates.  THen in your controller you should test to what type of template is necessary and load that.  ARe you familiar with template inheritance in codeigniter?

Comment: not familiar with templ inheritance - I am using Colin William's template library, but without any type of 'nesting'

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd first check the execution time limit in php settings. The situation you described looks very like that issue: sometimes script manages to get there in time, and sometimes not. ) More about that [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Second, yes, you should avoid logic heavy views. Honestly speaking, I don't know how to do it in CodeIgniter, but in Zend Framework there are so called view helpers, that can be used to separate the view-related (but heavy) logic from templates.

Finally, have you already profiled your script - with [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) or some other similar tool?

**UPDATE:** A case when "conditionals testing for post parameters" is sitting cosily within the view (and just resists all attempts to be moved into Controller) is... interesting, to say the least. I'm sorry, but what's the point of using MVC framework then?

Comment: agreed - the super view was built as a way to unify into a single view all possible blog post types, which are then displayed based on their `$post_type` - but I think this unification comes at the expense of too much processing when these big arrays hit the view and then there's a timeout